# Laravel 5.4 localhost:8000 no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Al momento de poner `php artisan serve` todo va bien, hasta que me dirijo a mi `localhost:8000` y me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\EEPAT/public/index.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\EEPAT\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\EEPAT/public/index.php'
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\EEPAT\server.php on line 21
```

La carpeta `EEPAT` la he obtenido por `git clone`, ya que comenzaré a programar sobre ese proyecto donde trabajo.

Comment: Si encontraste la solución, publica una nueva respuesta y acéptala.

Comment: Disculpa, no sabía que se podía hacer eso

Comment: Paloma AG, no hay problema, todos estamos para aprender. Bienvenida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya qué no pude entrar mediante php artisan serve, decidí hacerlo mediante localhost con xampp, el problema que tuve fue que no me dejaba ir a ninguna ruta, al parecer laravel tiene algunos problemas con la nueva versión de xampp, por lo cuál tuve que colocar index.php antes de la ruta a la que quiero ir, ejemplo:

http://localhost/carpeta_proyecto/public/index.php/ruta

De esta forma ya pude ingresar a todas las rutas sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

lo que te dice el error es que no tienes el archivos index.php en la carpeta public.
Si estas clonando el proyecto lo primero que debiste de hacer crear el .env si es que no lo tienes (ya que en muchos proyectos evitan subirlo a git), si ya lo tienes lo que sigue es ejecutar:

```
composer update
```

por si acaso tambien un :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

y ya deberia de funcionar.
Si aun no funciona lo que debes de hacer es fijarte en el .gitignore si se encuentra la path de public/index.php (lo cual seria muy raro), de todas formas tambien la puedes buscar dentro tu proyecto en la carpeta public el archivo index.php si no lo encuentras seguimos con crear un nuevo archivo **index.php** dentro de la carpeta **public** y copias y pegas este codigo:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Bueno eso seria todo si el problema continua no olvides volver a postear el resultado, y si resuelve tu error marca esta respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Ya hice todo lo que me dijiste, el archivo index.php se encuentra ahí, sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: pues otra cosa que se me ocurre es que la version de php con que se trabajo el proyecto que clonaste es mayor o muy menor a la que tienes instalada localmente, fijate que version es tu php y con cual esta trabajando el proyecto clonado

Comment: Hacer composer update es arriesgadísimo, imágina si estas con laravel 5.9.9 y haces hoy composer update te traeria laravel 8..

Answer (score 0):

Apunta un `vhost` a la carpeta public del proyecto, y revisa que en bootstrap tienes en la carpeta cache el archivo `servicios.php` y en storage/framework tienes `cache`, `views` y `sessions`.

Mira también que todos tengan permisos adecuados, usuario y grupo con el que pueda ejecutar tu apache/nginx

Comment: No entendí lo del vhost, ¿podrías explicarme lo que es?, las carpetas y los archivos se encuentran donde deberían y ¿cómo checo lo de los permisos?

Comment: ls -la en UNIX y si es windows simplemente ejecuta con permisos de administracion